Query entries for multiple dropdown field values
I'm currently querying entries successfully like so for the associatedBusiness
field:
{% set query = query.businessVertical(queryParam) %}
However I have two other dropdown fields that I would like to check against:

I tries this but doesn't seem to work:
{% set query = query.search('businessVertical:' ~ queryParam ~ ' OR  businessVertical2:' ~ queryParam ~ ' OR  businessVertical3:' ~ queryParam) %}
Not sure of any other ways to write this syntax with Craft3

I finally found something that worked after trying various methods:
{% set allEntries = query.all() %}

    {% set allResults = allEntries|filter(entry =>
        entry.associatedBusiness == queryParam or
        entry.businessVertical2 == queryParam or
        entry.businessVertical3 == queryParam
    ) %}

    {% set currentPage = craft.app.request.pageNum %}
    {% set total = allResults|length %}

    {% set offset = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize %}
    {% set pageEntries = allResults|slice(offset, pageSize) %}

    {% set pageInfo = {
        first: 1,
        last: ceil(total / pageSize),
        total: total,
        currentPage: currentPage,
        limit: pageSize,
        offset: offset
    } %}

and if you want to add paging you can do
{% if pageInfo.total > pageSize %}
                    <div class="paginationHolder">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            {% if currentPage > 1 %}
                                <li><a href="{{ url(craft.app.request.pathInfo, {page: currentPage-1}) }}">Previous</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                            
                            {% if currentPage < pageInfo.last %}
                                <li><a href="{{ url(craft.app.request.pathInfo, {page: currentPage+1}) }}">Next</a></li>
                            {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                {% endif %}


Not sure I'd recommend this approach - better to get the stuff you need up front rather than fetching everything and then filtering it. Have you checked Yii's documentation on where? https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querytrait#where()-detail - You can add this in a Craft element query something like this: craft.entries.where(['or', 'fieldColumnName1 = "something"', 'fieldColumnName2 = "another"']).all()
